# Request for a New tag "technical details"

Tags: feature-request

I do have many technical doubts but there is no tag "technical details " so I have to use "mining technical details so please add this tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can use the 'protocol' tag. If that does not suit your questions, please let me know and I can add the tag.

Comment: it wont suit as i do not generally ask about protocals

Comment: Note that the 'protocol' tag is specifically for questions related to the Monero protocol, not other protocols.

Comment: yes i understood the context already as per the context of monero i am asking to add new tag technical details / technical questions

Comment: All right. I've added the tag through this question: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/14116/what-is-the-maximum-possible-value-of-nonce

Comment: thanks for adding

Comment: You're welcome!